# Getting the value between 2nd and 3rd slash

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, 1. I am trying to apply regular expression or even extracting the last 6 digits of a Pandas Dataframe Column (all rows).

Basically I am trying to extract value between the second and third slash 0000/00000/00/000 in a pandas column.
My function for extracting the last 6 digits of a pandas dataframe 'data_extract' with column name as 'extract' is  `data_extracted=data_extract.extract.str[:-4]`

The df.head() looks like this[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to either extract the last 6 digits and store in a new column or extract the number between 2nd and 3rd slashes '/' and store in a new column in pandas dataframe.
As  Suggested by Mohamed Thasin, Applying the Lamba expression [![enter image description here][2]][2]
as `df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/'))` yields then in an array by splitting on the basis of '/' . How do i get the 2nd Index of the array?

Comment: @Op, so are you trying to extract the last 6 digits? Or the values between the second and third slash? Because you've asked for both and they're not the same thing. That's why I asked for a [mcve].

Comment: i am sorry guys , i didnot mean to create this. this is my first day on python.

Comment: @coldspeed Got it! I was just telling him to not be discouraged from the site permanantly because of someone here having a bad day ;)

Comment: @IamKarim1992 Fair enough, but please at least provide enough detail to your question that makes it clear what it is you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this ,

```
df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[2]), This splits the Dataframe (all rows) for every occurrence of '/' and then takes the value between 2nd and 3rd '/'.
```

if it contains unexpected format,

```
df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[2] if(len(x.split('/')))==4 else '')
```

This is for sanity check, if after split the list doesn't contain 4 elements then instead of throwing index out of bound error it fills in '' a blank.

Comment: This does not address the `even extracting the last 6 digits of a Pandas Dataframe Column`.

Comment: @coldspeed  - I answered for `I am trying to extract value between the second and third slash 0000/00000/00/000 in a pandas column`

Comment: Yes but it does not address the other thing OP said. That was the whole point behind my comment. To provide a [mcve]. Not to downvote for the sake of it. The question isn't clear at all.

Comment: like in R we have a substring() function. Does Pandas provide such . ex. if i want to substring entire row value.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work on all rows . DataFrameName['Column'] is the data containing all rows . The code line DataframeName.Column.extract.str.split('/')[2] works only on the first row.

Comment: This yields an array against the row value and shows something like above in the screenshot. But to get specific 3rd element of that array. The [2] after the split gives index out of bound error.

Comment: using apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[2]) gives , 'list index out of range ' error.

Comment: Thanks Thasin . Could u point to to any online link for learning lambda expression.

Comment: @IamKarim1992 - i suggest you to follow this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html
and `see also` . all the best for your pandas journey. If you have any particular doubts you could mail me also :)

Answer (score 3):

The [regex](https://regexr.com/3r5v5) here seems to be able to get whatever between the 2nd and 3rd slash. The link has all the explanations for all the syntax that I used.

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}([^\/]*)\/.*$
```

Basically, I used the negated set to match everything except the delimiter (/) and capture everything between the second and third delimiter

hope it helps :)